# UIButton configuration with highlight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've created a `UIbutton` (in storyboard) to add an object to favourites list, but I'm having trouble configuring it. This adds the object to favorites, but how to un-favorite it?

I've been searching and thinking for a while and my thought was to make some an if-statement in the manageHighlightAndFave like: if favButton `state = highlighted`, remove from favorites and remove highlight. Else, add to favorite and add highlight. Is this good, or what is the preferred way of doing what I'm trying? I would love an example as I am new to programming.

```
-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(manageHighlightAndFave:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)manageHighlightAndFave:(UIButton*)favButton {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                        object:selectedObject];
    [favButton setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

PS. Linked with "touch down" in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend you make a custom-Button. following refer code.

First, Make a following button.
File-New-File-Cocoa Touch-Objective-C Class
[image]
[image]
**FavoriteButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FavoriteButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isFavorite;
@end
```

---

**FavoriteButton.m**

```
#import "FavoriteButton.h"

@implements FavoriteButton : UIButton

@synthesize isFavorite;
...
@end
```

---

Second, in Storyboard you link a FavoriteButton. refer a following image.
Are in the right panel at storyboard. before, clicked your originally UIButton

[image]

YourViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FavoriteButton.h"

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet FavoriteButton *favoriteButton;
@end
```

---

```
@implements YourViewController : UIViewController
@synthesize favoriteButton;


-(void) viewDidLoad
{
   self.favoriteButton = [[FavoriteButton alloc] initWithFrame:...]];
   //favoriteButton.isFavorite = NO; (already set in storyboard)
   ...
}

-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(manageHighlightAndFave:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)manageHighlightAndFave:(FavoriteButton *)favButton {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemSelected"
                                                        object:selectedObject];

    //true-false(YES-NO) Toggled. but isFavorite property is Must be initialized to false.
    favButton.isFavorite = !favButton.isFavorite;

    if(favButton.isFavorite)
    {
        favButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_star_image"];
        [favButton setHighlighted:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        favButton.imageView.image = nil;
        [favButton setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get 4 errors: Property "isFavorite" not found on object of type UIButton x 2 and "No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector "setHighlighted" x 2. And should the Notification to add fav be placed in the 'if" block, and the notification to remove fav be placed it in 'else' block? Or am I misunderstanding this?